# Integration Test is Not Reaching Controller When Debugging

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have an integration test that attempts to invoke a controller API, but whenever I debug the test it doesn't reach the breakpoint of my controller.

```
// IntegrationTest.cs
var httpClient = _application.CreateDefaultClient(); // BaseAddress = http://localhost
    
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("v1/values");
    
Assert.AreEqual(200, (int)response.StatusCode);

// ValuesController.cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetValues()
{
    return Ok(); // Breakpoint is set here.
}
```

Both projects are set to **Debug** but it didn't solve the issue. Are there other configurations that I need to set?

Note that I also have a unit test project and it's able to debug without any problem.

Comment: You are starting both the IntegrationTest project and the API project right ?

Comment: I don't. But what you said gave me an idea on what to do. I need to use Release in the API project and Debug in the IntegrationTest project. 

Thanks for the help!